# Remove item in array without update view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have dinamic tabs (Angular UI Bootstrap) in my view this way:

```
 <uib-tabset active="1" id="tabs" class="col-md-10">
            <uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in filaCtrl.tabs" ng-click="filaCtrl.getChatTab(tab.protocolo)">
                <uib-tab-heading >
                    <div style='display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;'>
                        <h5 style='margin-right: 10px;'>Protocolo: {{tab.protocolo}}</h5>
                        <h7 ng-md-icon icon='cancel' style='fill:#F44336' size='16' ng-click='filaCtrl.closeTab(tab.protocolo, $index)'><h7>
                    <div>
                </uib-tab-heading>
            <div class="tab-content">
(...)
```

My function filaCtrl.closeTab() remove a tab, i.e., a item in array filaCtrl.tabs. But when a item is removed the view is updated and 'close' all tabs, i.e., refresh page.

```
self.closeTab = function (protocolo, $index) {
          self.tabs.splice($index, 1);
        };
```

How can i remove item without refresh my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` does a two-way-binding so that objects changed in the view update the controller and vice-versa.

If you want to one-time-bind the the `tabs` array, you could define your `ng-repeat` statement as:

```
<uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in ::filaCtrl.tabs" ng-click="filaCtrl.getChatTab(tab.protocolo)">
```

Note that the `::` syntax will one-time-bind your array.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior in Angular (and the magic of data binding). You will need to make a copy of `self.tabs` and use that in your `ng-repeat`

```
self.tabsCopy = angular.copy(self.tabs);
```

Then you can do

```
<uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in filaCtrl.tabsCopy" ng-click="filaCtrl.getChatTab(tab.protocolo)">
```

However, note that your `closeTab` function uses the index of the tab in your array. So if the user closes multiple tabs, you will run into issues since your `tabs` and `tabsCopy` array will be different.

A better approach is to use some kind of variable like `tab.open` or `tab.closed` to track the state of a tab. Then you can do something like

```
<uib-tab ng-repeat="tab in filaCtrl.tabs" ng-click="filaCtrl.getChatTab(tab.protocolo)">
  <uib-tab-heading ng-if="tab.open>
    ...
```

Comment: Doesn't work. When valeu of tab.open changes refresh the page too.